# How to print DD/MM/YYYY on JDateChooser Field?

Tags: java, swing, jdatechooser

How to print `DD/MM/YYYY` on `JDateChooser` field?

```
JDateChooser jdc=new JDateChooser();
```

i am using `JDateChooser` for selecting date, But i also want to facilitate type date in `DD/MM/YYYY` format.

[image]

Comment: which JDateChooser you use?

Comment: Take a look at the `PromptSupport` API in the SwingLabs, SwingX libraries

Comment: jcalendar-1.4 - JDateChooser i had used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The api has a method setDateFormatString

http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/api/com/toedter/calendar/JDateChooser.html#setDateFormatString(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

From the [api](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/api/com/toedter/calendar/JDateChooser.html), I'd use the JDateChooser(java.lang.String dateFormatString, boolean startEmpty) constructor as so;

```
JDateChooser jdc = new JDateChooser("DD/MM/YYYY", true);
```